# Re-fetch & Re-render component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a react-native mobile project and I'm using fetch API to get datas from server. So my problem is when I navigate other component in my app, I update some values (via fetch in server) and fetch the new ones, but when I go back to home scene I see old fetched datas, how I can update it everytime I comeback to home scene?

Here is my home scene:

```
export default class Inside extends Component {

    componentWillMount (){
            alert(this.props.userid + this.state.userid);
            fetch('http://xxx/fetch_info', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    check: this.props.userid
                }),
            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    alert(responseJson.money + " " + responseJson.mesage);
                    this.setState({
                        example: ex
                    });

                }).catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
            });
        }

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ....
            check: this.props.exp
        };
    }

render(){
 <Text> {this.state.stuff} </Text>
 }
}
```

My scenes :

```
<Scene key="main">
    <Scene key="home" component={Home}  initial/>
    <Scene  key ="money" component={Money} />
</Scene>
```

So everytime I go back I want data to be fetched automatically, but I dont get it how to do it..?

Comment: Have you considered or are you using `redux`?

Comment: I'm kinda newbee, I know more less whats redux but maybe I can use it after I do more in my project.. Redux looks scary for newbies i guess

Comment: Don't worry about it. `redux` is a state container, exactly what you want. I doubt if anybody would be willing to answer this  question further than this, because it's too big. Have fun learning `redux`!

Comment: Ok.. I take it as and suggestion to my question, thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if it doesn't re-fetch that means your component lifecycle is messed up. Try adding componentWillUnmount() and see if you components gets destroyed before going to a new component during navigation.

Comment: You don't necessarily need redux, but you do need to manage that data in the state of a higher level/parent component. I'm also new to React and was reading this post recently, unsure if I should learn redux next (it's a bit intimidating): https://medium.com/@blairanderson/you-probably-dont-need-redux-1b404204a07f

Comment: thank you all guys, I will check the link and yeah I will try componentwillunmount and let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in your project react-navigation when you comeback to your "home sceen" as you say instead of using
`this.props.navigation.navigate('yourScreen');`
you can use `this.props.navigation.replace('yourScreen');`
This will cause your page to reload. It's not a good practice because your loose all previous navigation(the screens you navigated before) but a temporary fix.